# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Access is denied

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, access-denied

I build SP 2010 project through VS 2010. On deploying through visual studio, I get following error:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Access is denied.

Any idea, what's wrong ??

Comment: have you opened vs2010 as administrator..?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

go to Central Administration -> Application Management -> Configure quota and locks

in that Site Lock Information Section.

select Lock Status for this site -> Not locked

Hope it helps...

Comment: I checked, its already Not locked.

Comment: also check database is in readonly and site collection administrator..

Answer (score 0):

run this script in powershell, it has todo with editing you web.config file.

```
$cs = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 
$cs.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = $false  
$cs.Update()
```

> before updating the web.config programmatically, the 'Remote
>   Administrator Access Denied' flag from the content service has to be
>   switched off, otherwise, the SharePoint server
>   spontaneously throws this misleading 'Access Denied' error message

http://software-smith.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/writing-programmatically-to-webconfig.html